# OpenLayers with MapServer

Tags: openlayers, mapserver

I have setup MapServer (MS4W) on my local Windows machine, and can access the map with this link `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?template=openlayers&layers=all&map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps1/osm-google.map`

My requirement is I want directly jump to a lat long with zoom value and show marker on lat long.

I looked into OpenLayers and with a overview I think it is good for my requirement. How can I setup my `map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps1/osm-google.map` with OpenLayers?

Comment: As I understand it the openlayers template is really just a quick way of testing/demoing your mapserver service, if you want to be able to go to a particular location, you'll need to drop that template and use a WMS or WFS, though even then you can use application/openlayers& as output format for the WMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you should configure MapServer as a WMS. To `zoom` to a location of interest you'd need set an appropriate bounding box and map image size specified in pixels.

You can check whether you already have a WMS configured (or part configured) by using the following request:

> http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps1/osm-google.map&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

and similarly for a WFS like:

> http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps1/osm-google.map&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&

Let's consider a MapServer based service for India as below. There is a WMS configured as well but the output here is using the openlayers template:

[image: MapServer service output using openlayers template]

Let's say I want to have a link that goes directly to the small cluster of faults in the North.

I need to use a WMS GetMap operation to specify the area of interest, to *zoom* to that location, something like:

> http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_GSI_Geology/wms?language=eng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=29.94358696243455853,77.35665599784030633,31.59091424368455847,79.93718124679318748&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=1496&HEIGHT=955&LAYERS=IND_GSI_2M_Faults&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&TRANSPARENT=FALSE&

Which gives us an image/png output like below:

[image: MapServer WMS image/png output]

Or if you wanted an OpenLayers output you could change the `FORMAT=image/png&` parameter to `FORMAT=application/openlayers&` to give you:

[image: MapServer WMS application/openlayers output]